# Ridiculously slow unique_ptr dtor call when debugger is attached (msvc)

Tags: c++, debugging, visual-c++, unique-ptr

```
struct test_struct
{
    test_struct() {}
    ~test_struct() {}
};

#include <vector>
#include <memory>
#include <cstdio>

int main()
{
    printf("ctor begin\n");
    {
        std::vector<std::unique_ptr<test_struct>> test_vec;
        const int count = 100000;

        for (auto i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            test_vec.emplace_back(new test_struct);
        }
        printf("dtor begin\n");
    }
    printf("dtor end\n");
}
```

I'm using VS2010, and found some ridiculous performance issue. The code above works well both in debug and release build (ctrl+f5), but when debugger is attached(f5), dtor call for unique_ptr class is intolerably slow. The result machine code is fairly optimized, so I don't expect that it's compiler issue rather than debugger's, but I don't know how to deal with it. My question is

- Is this problem able to be reproduced on your machine?
- What's the reason of this behaviour?
- Is there any workaround?

Comment: Try flushing after each printf.

Comment: @Pubby: That's not going to make a difference, there's only 3 `printf`s total, not one for each loop iteration.

Comment: I was able to reproduce this on my VS2010 express edition.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The slowdown is caused by memory checking that occurs whenever memory is freed. However, this is a special system-/debugger-level heap, and isn't anything you can control from within your program.

There's a [great article on the issue](http://preshing.com/20110717/the-windows-heap-is-slow-when-launched-from-the-debugger). To summarize: you have to set an environment variable to disable it!

Luckily, you can set project-specific environment variables from the Debugging options in the Project Settings for your project, so that the environment variable is only applied to your program.

I used this simplified program to test:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "ctor begin" << std::endl;
    {
        std::vector<std::unique_ptr<int>> test_vec;

        for (unsigned i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
            test_vec.emplace_back(new int);

        std::cout << "dtor begin" << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << "dtor end" << std::endl;
}
```

By setting `_NO_DEBUG_HEAP=1` as an environment variable (either system-wide, which I won't recommend, or through the Debugging options), the code runs in roughly the same amount of time irrespective of whether or not the debugger is attached.